# How does the max in MapReduce get its values from and what do they represent?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to understand how does MapReduce works at the backend. This piece of code gives me the word with the most occurrence, which is 'the' in my dataset. How does the max value work, what does it represent?

```
  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  int max =0;
  Text maxWord = new Text();

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum=0;
      for (IntWritable value : values) {
          sum += value.get();
      }

      if(sum > max){
          max = sum;
          maxWord.set(key);
      }           
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about how MapReduce works and specifically how reduce works, so first of all, I would advise you to read a tutorial before proceeding, like [this one](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html).

Now, regarding your question, I assume that it works only if you have a single reducer.

What it does, is that for all the keys (i.e. words) that the reducer reads, it keeps the one with the maximum occurences. Each key, representing a word, has a list of values, that I guess, are generated by a mapper that outputs `(word, 1)` pairs. So the input of the reducer is, e.g. `("the", <1,1,1,1,1,1,1>)` - this could be different if a combiner is involved.

Then, all that is left to do for the reducer is sum up the ones of this list and get the total count of each word, e.g. `the --> 7`
However, if more reducers were engaged, each would keep one word, so you would have as many answers, as the number of the reducers.

The `max` variable, simply keeps the number of occurences of the most frequent word, till now. If another word has more occurences than `max`, then it is the new most frequent word. Note that `max` is initialized outside the `reduce()` method, which means that its value is kept for the next keys (i.e. words) of the same reducer.